# Return approximate multiple matches to a ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, macros

I want to return multiple matches from a column to a ComboBox. So if I have a column like this named "Variable:, and search for "variable1"

[image]

Then I want an output like this in the ComboBox. And if no matches found then "no Match".[image]

Comment: What if you had `zVariable` in Column A - should that appear in the ComboBox?

Comment: Also is the ComboBox a Form or ActiveX control? Is it on the sheet or on a UserForm ?

Comment: @Robin - Its on a UserForm . And only approximate matches appear in the combo box for whatever we search in the TextBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the assumption that the 'approximate match' is a) case insensitive, and b) just requires the search string to be somewhere inside the `Range` value. Try this code inside the `UserForm`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim strValueToApproximatelyMatch As String
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim lngResultCount As Long

    'get candidate values and put to an array
    Set rngSource = Sheet1.Range("A2:A10")

    'get value to match approximately
    strValueToApproximatelyMatch = Me.TextBox1.Value

    'clear combo box
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear

    'set result count to 0
    lngResultCount = 0

    'iterate array and look for approximate match to input
    For lngCounter = 1 To rngSource.Rows.Count
        'get candidate
        Set rngCell = rngSource.Cells(lngCounter, 1)
        'test candidate against value to approximately match
        If InStr(1, rngCell.Value, strValueToApproximatelyMatch, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            'add to list if test passed
            Me.ComboBox1.AddItem rngCell.Value
            'increment result count
            lngResultCount = lngResultCount + 1
        End If
    Next lngCounter

    'add the no match if result count =0
    If lngResultCount = 0 Then
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "No Match"
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! works like a charm..and as for no matches found, probably I can count the values in the CombBox, would return a nomatch if the count is 0..

Comment: @user2458552 - I updated the sample code for the 'no match' bit - guess you could use the count of items in the ComboBox - but I just created a separate counter instead. Same difference :)